# Jailbroken ipad 2 transfer pdfs

Tags: ipad, pdf, jailbreak

I just jailbroke my old Ipad 2 to add some pdfs to it. Done it with 3uTools and connected to it with WINSCP (im on a PC with Win10). Everything works fine except when i transfer my PDFs to the IPad they dont show up on iBooks.

Anyone know how i can transfer and open my pdfs on it ? iTunes dont work anymore, it recognizes my ipad but it doesnt sync.

I uploaded copies of my Pdfs to /private/var/mobile/Media/Books and all the folders inside it. But none worked.

Comment: Might be easier to use an alternative PDF reader on the iPad. Books probably has its own metadata stored in a file somewhere, and without that it won't see the PDFs.

Comment: Surely you didn't need to jailbreak it to add some PDFs....? Normally, don't you just Share the PDFs to Books.

Comment: The problem is nothing is compatible anymore. I cant download apps and i cant share anything with iTunes. How can i install a PDF Reader manually and wich one/ where i can find one compatible wth such an Old iPad ?